# flatbuffer "include" statement does not work for enum

Tags: typescript, flatbuffers

I am building on Ubuntu 17.10 with flatc version 1.7

I have a .fbs schema file defining different enumerations that are used multiple times throughout my flatbuffer files. However, when I include the .fbs file containing all of the enums and compile into TypeScript, I can't use the enums.

I have included other files before and utilized "tables" defined in them. Do include statements only work when using tables, or can other data types be included?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific. What exact error are you getting? Are the enums missing from the generates .js files? What exactly is the problem?
Includes are intended to work for enums, yes.

Comment: The typescript file will have a reference in the form of: _transitionInputType():NS11858840996067445030.F8fbs.InputType_                 but there is no import statement included at the top of the file. I'm not sure where that NS118... term comes from, but when I try to compile my webpack it says that the build fails because it's a unknown namespace. If I use a table instead of an enum, the include statement gets added. I'm not sure if I'm missing a command line argument or if this is a bug, but it is not working for me.

Comment: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/4677